# Where can I find the theorem that says an n order diffeq has n solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I study engineering not mathematics and I feel my theoretical understanding of differential equations is SO wishy washy.

I'm not interested in proving such a theorem at the moment, but I want to know which is the theorem that guarantees an n-order differential equation has n solutions. Also, I'd like to know some intuition behind this fact.

I'm frustrated by this theorem because I stumbled upon the equation $\theta''+k\theta'^2=0$ and have only found as a solution $\theta=c_1+\ln(c_2+t)$. I'm not sure if the non-linearity is causing there to be only one solution, or if there are two in this case as well...

Also, is the number of solutions given by the number of terms in the solution (which would exclude in the previous example $c_1$)? Or is it given by the number of constants? The amount of linearly independent terms?

Comment: Do you know term " Linearly dependent" and "Linearly independent".

Comment: @Chiranjeev: based on the last question, I'd say so...

Comment: @abiessu so question should be "n-linearly independent solutions"

Comment: @Chiranjeev:  it looks to me like a question of reaching that understanding, namely that the "number of solutions" being referred to is the "number of linearly independent solutions", and not the uncountable set of solutions produced under a constant like $c_1$...

Comment: Or "the $n$-parameter family of solutions" was meant?

Answer (score 1):

The answer has two parts.

The first part is the transformation of a differential equation of order n into a system of dimension n of first order. This is the usual setting $y_1=x$, $y_2=x'$, ..., $y_n=x^{(n-1)}$.

The second part is the existence theorem resp. Picard-Lindelöf. It says that every initial value problem has at least a local solution. And the initial value has $n$ free parameters. Of course these $n$ parameters can be replaced via any bijective function.

So in the end, a differential equation involving up to the $n$-th derivative requires $n$ integration constants in the solution.

---

In that sense, your solution is complete, in has two integration constants for a second order differential equation. Since the equation is not linear, one can not expect the solution to be a linear combination of basis solutions. In general one can not even expect that the solution can be separated as a sum of terms involving just one constant as it is the case here.